# index.js:1 Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering

Tags: find

showing this error while I'm login to my website when debugging on and after 1 sec logout

its not working with only on localhost .this is showing while debugging on otherwise nothing happened.please someone help to find solution.